# Gallery view in Android is not Starting as follows:

Tags: android, gallery

m not able to set my images of gallery to start from left by default, they show up in the center of the gallery, leaving the left space empty.
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    // set gallery to left side
    MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) g.getLayoutParams();
    mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels / 2 + (imageWidth/2)), mlp.topMargin,
                mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
```

OR

That is easy just set gallery on another item:

```
myGallery.setSelection(4);
```

Comment: thanx it was helpful.
but mGallery.setSelection(4);
did not work for me.